# Displaying ListView in alertDailog android

Tags: android, listview

When the user clicks the item of list View a alert Dialog box will be displayed to the user with options like "view","delete" or "update"
the list view item. Clicking on the list view item for the first time displays the alert Dialog with options but when i click another list View item or the same list View item the second time the app crashes.Thanks in advance.

Error :java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

```
  //The main list displayed when the user log in successfully  
  ListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ListView2 = new ListView(this);  //List to be displayed in the alert Dailog box     
    ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            long i =  ListView.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
            showAlertDailog();//The dialog box method
        }
    });
    if(mCursorAdapter == null) //To check if the list is empty
    {
        TextView emptyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
        emptyTextView.setText("No Notes");
        ListView.setEmptyView(emptyTextView);
    }else {
        mCursorAdapter = new DataCursorAdapter(this, null);
        ListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
    }
 public void showAlertDailog()
{
    String [] items = {"View","Delete","Update"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_todo_2,R.id.textView4,items);
    ListView2.setAdapter(adapter);


    final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
           builder.setView(ListView2)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Close",null);
    android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I've added few more lines of code. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly what you need

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button mDoneButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDoneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        mDoneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final CharSequence[] items = {
                "Rajesh", "Mahesh", "Vijayakumar"
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                // Do something with the selection
                mDoneButton.setText(items[item]);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
}
```

http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/04/alert-dialog-dialog-with-item-list.html

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I tried to upvote you but it says vote cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded but do not change the publicly post score.

Comment: I am not asking for votes .. you can accept answer if it helped you.. it will helps others too..

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

CharSequence[] animals = arrayList.toArray(new String[arrayList.size()]);

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        dialogBuilder.setItems(animals, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                String selectedText = animals[item].toString();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialogObject.show();

This is simple way to display list inside alert dialog, where in arraylist just add string whatever you have to display inside alert dialog list.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String[] listItems = { "Colour", "Font Size", };
                if (listItems[position].equals("Font Size")) {


                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Settings.this );

                        // set title
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose Font Size");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                    // current activity

                                }
                              })
                            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                            // create alert dialog
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                            // show it
                            alertDialog.show();


                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried to implement this code but it didn't work. I've found the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showAlertDailog(Context context) {
ListView listView=new ListView(context);
yourLayout.LayoutParams params= yourLayout.LayoutParams(Yourlayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,Yourlayout.LayoutPa
rams.MATCH_PARENT);
listview.setLayoutParams(params);
String [] items = {"View","Delete","Update"}; 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
       builder.setView(listView)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Close",(dialog,something)->{dialog.dismiss()});
android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

}